# Communication between local kernels

Tags: parallelization, kernel

this is my first post but you have already helped me so many times that I have to start by saying thanks a lot!

I have a really long calculation to do, and I have used the Evaluation->Kernel configuration options to create 2 new local kernels and divided the task in three groups of little ones. The problem is that I don't know how to share the information between different notebooks running on different local kernels. 
Can you help me?

Thanks again anyway.

Comment: Just curious: Is there a reason why you don't use the parallelism features of Mathematica, using SubKernels? Those include easy-to-use functionality for information sharing.

Comment: In V10 you could perhaps use the cloud (using `CloudPut` and `CloudGet`) to share values. Of course, this is useful only if the calculations are expensive compared   to communication.

Comment: As celtschk said, read up on parallelization in Mathematica.  `Evaluation->Kernel configuration options` are *not* for configuring parallel kernels.  Communication is only easy if you use parallelization.  Rom's answer also refer to using parallel subkernels.

Comment: @Szabolcs You have experience with low level kernel communication I believe; how would one send data from one *master* kernel to another as described in this question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That is definitely an exciting topic, but I didn't post it because I felt it would be starting the OP down the wrong path.  Building a full communication frameworks is almost certainly not what he *needs* even if he phrased the question this way ... I can try to write something though.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am not that experienced either, unfortunately, but I wrote something.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Mathematica's parallel tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/Overview.html), which already implement inter-kernel communication.  What I show below is not the typical way to use parallelization.  I try to follow your requirements more closely.  I do strongly recommend you read through the parallelization docs and learn the basics before you use this though.

When using the parallelization framework, we have one *main kernel* and several *subkernels*.  Parallelization works by dividing the task into parts automatically (as I understand you want to do this manually) and evaluating the parts in parallel on the suberkernels.  E.g. `ParalellTable` will do this mostly automatically for a `Table`-like computation.  Now we're going to do something similar semi-manually:

First, launch 3 kernels:

```
LaunchKernels[3]
```

Then determine which symbols need to be sent to the subkernels, and pass them to `DistributeDefinitions`:

```
a = 1
f[x_] := a x^2
b = 2

DistributeDefinitions[f,b]
```

Note that `a` will also be distributed because `f` depends on it.

`Kernels[]` will give you the handles to all subkernels.

```
ParallelEvaluate[f[b], Kernels[][[1]]]
```

will evaluate `f[b]` on the first kernel.  You could also just refer to this kernel by its `$KernelID`, which will be `1` for the first startup up kernel: `ParallelEvaluate[f[b], 1]`.

The result will be automatically returned to the main kernel.

`ParallelEvaluate[f[b]]` will evaluate `f[b]` on all three kernels simultaneously.

The problem with `ParallelEvaluate` is that it blocks: it won't return until the suberkenl evaluation has finished.  So if you need to do different evaluations on the three kernels, then `ParallelEvaluation` is not the most convenient solutions.

If you need to do asynchronous evaluations, e.g. you need to use the main kernel while the subkernels are working, then use the lower level constructs described in [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConcurrencyManagingParallelProcesses.html).

A small example:

```
task1 = ParallelSubmit[1 + 1]
```

will submit a task to be evaluated.

```
task2 = ParallelSubmit[5!]
```

will submit another task

```
WaitAll[{task1, task2}]
```

will start both, wait wait for them to finish and will return the results in a list as `{2, 120}`.

---

The parallel tools use MathLink (called WSTP since version 10) to communicate between the main kernel and subkernels.  Theoretically you could implement a communication framework yourself using MathLink, but this is likely going to take more effort than what's reasonable to spend on this problem ...

Here's a short example to give a taste of how this would work:

`LinkLaunch` will take care of launching a kernel, creating a MathLink connection, and connecting to it:

```
In[1]:= kernel = LinkLaunch["/Applications/Mathematica\\ 10.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -mathlink"]    
Out[1]= LinkObject["/Applications/Mathematica\\ 10.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -mathlink", 73, 4]
```

These steps could also be broken down, and you could use `LinkCreate` and `LinkConnect`.

```
In[2]:= LinkRead[kernel]    
Out[2]= InputNamePacket["In[1]:= "]
```

Let's send something to that kernel for evaluation:

```
In[3]:= LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[1 + 1]]
```

And read back the result:

```
In[4]:= LinkRead[kernel]    
Out[4]= ReturnPacket[2]
```

If the evaluation has not finished yet, `LinkRead` will block until there is something to read from the link.  To avoid this, you can check whether the link is ready before reading using `LinkReadyQ`.  Be careful not to try to read from a link that won't be able to send anything, or the kernel will lock up.

Unfortunately the workings of MathLink are not quite as well documented as the rest of Mathematica, but you'll find several example [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPWolframLanguageFunctions.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPPackets.html).

Comment: Thanks for the second example, it made me learn something new and useful, it can be useful for running a parallel task without ParallelSubmit, ie   to be able to run an instruction on a specific kernel without a queue, and without blocking the main kernel.

Comment: It has allowed me to answer a question I had. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89886/66

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to use in the main notebook the `DistributeDefinitions[{list of yoyr variables}]`command.

It will automatically share all mentioned mathematica names and it's content to all kernels. This in turn will make it available in all notebooks related to those kernels.
But why do you use some notebooks for parallelization? Any tasks could be run in parallel from the one notebook - just use parallel routines instead of usual.

Comment: Following the procedure in the question where Notebooks are given different *master* kernels via the **Evaluation** menu this simply doesn't work.  Sorry, but -1. :-/